# How To Display A Video From Base64 In React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am converting a video to Base64 and storing it in Amazon S3. I am then retrieving it from Amazon S3 and receiving the raw Base64 data. **How do I change the raw Base64 into a format React Native Expo Video component will accept and properly render?**

I tried feeding the Base64 directly into the source portion of the uri:

```
<Video source={{uri:Base64}} />
```

and I've tried assigning the Base64 to a local uri using expo FileSystem:

```
FileSystem.downloadAsync(
              file,
              FileSystem.documentDirectory + "video.mov"
            ).then(({ uri }) => {
                setVideo(uri);

<Video source={{uri:video}} />
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Out of curiosity.. why encode it as bas64? It makes 33% larger

Comment: It was a slightly arbitrary choice; I need a way to store the raw data. What is a good alternative to base64?

Comment: Just store the file itself. Base64 is a specific encoding for places where you can only use 7 out of 8 bits, like embedded in text. The best thing you can do is to just *not* do that.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that about base64, thanks! I'm just wondering how to get the contents of the file from the uri (file:// and so on).

Comment: How do you get it now? What did you convert to base64 before?

Comment: I am using expo FileSystem to read a file of the form file:// and returning it as a base64 string. The only two options in this file reading system are base64 and utf8. Is there a better way to read/store the video?

Comment: Ah, very strange that they don't offer a way to read files as a blob, buffer or u8intArray. All those those make more sense than base64.. Blobs can just be directly used in the fetch body, so it's strange!

Comment: I will find a different file reading library which has blobs, buffers and u8intArray. Thank you so much for your help!